# Magento 2 - Load values in di.xml from a helper class

Tags: magento2, layout, helper

Currently the template is defined like this:

**Company/PdfDesign/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Company\PdfDesign\Model\CompanyDesign">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="templateFiles" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="extras" xsi:type="string">Company_PdfDesign::pdf/table/extras.phtml</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

However, I want to make this dynamic and load it from the settings, so I tried to use a helper like seen [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html):

**Company/PdfDesign/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Company\PdfDesign\Model\CompanyDesign">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="templateFiles" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="extras" xsi:type="helper" helper="Company\PdfDesign\Helper\Table\Extras::getTemplate"></item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

But if I flush cache from CLI then I get alot of XML errors.´

```
Invalid Document 
Element 'item', attribute '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}type': The QName value 'helper' of the xsi:type attribute does not resolve to a type definition.
Line: 11

Element 'item': The type definition is abstract.
Line: 11

Internal error: xmlSchemaXPathProcessHistory, The state object to be removed is not the first in the list.
Line: 10

Internal error: xmlSchemaValidateChildElem, calling xmlRegExecPushString2().
Line: 9

Internal error: xmlSchemaValidateElem, calling xmlSchemaStreamValidateChildElement().
Line: 9

Internal error: xmlSchemaDocWalk, calling xmlSchemaValidateElem().
Line: 9
```

How can I load the value from a helper instead of hardcoding it?

---

**Company\PdfDesign\Model\CompanyDesign**

```
<?php
/**
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2015 Fooman Limited (http://www.fooman.co.nz)
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace Company\PdfDesign\Model;

use \Fooman\PdfCore\Helper\Logo;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

/**
 * Design source for Default Design
 */
class CompanyDesign implements \Fooman\PdfDesign\Model\Api\DesignInterface
{
    ...
    
    public function __construct(
        array $templateFiles = []
    ) {
        $this->templateFiles = $templateFiles;
    }
    
    ...

    public function getTemplateFiles()
    {
        return $this->templateFiles;
    }

    ...

}
```

**vendor/fooman/pdfdesign-m2/src/Model/TemplateFileDecider.php**

```
<?php
namespace Fooman\PdfDesign\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException;

/**
 * pick template file based on chosen pdf design
 */
class TemplateFileDecider
{
    private $defaultDesign;

    public function __construct(
        DefaultDesign $defaultDesign
    ) {
        $this->defaultDesign = $defaultDesign;
    }

    public function pick(Api\DesignInterface $design, $templateFor)
    {
        $designTemplates = $design->getTemplateFiles() + $this->defaultDesign->getTemplateFiles();
        if (!isset($designTemplates[$templateFor])) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('No template set for %1', $templateFor));
        }
        return $designTemplates[$templateFor];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain in details what you are try to achive?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya, im not sure what more details you need. Can you explain?

Comment: my question is that which template and how you want to change?

Comment: can you please provide content of the Company\PdfDesign\Model\CompanyDesign class? In order we could try to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: @MagestyApps i added more details.

Comment: Ok, then why can't you dynamically set the necessary template in Company\PdfDesign\Model\ CompanyDesign:: getTemplateFiles() method?

Comment: @MagestyApps, because in my attempt I get errors as you see in my question.
Currently I solve it by loading the data from the backend config, but I search for a helper solution.

Comment: The type "helper" for arguments is not allowed in di.xml but in layouts only. In di you will have to use the "object" type.
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/build/di-xml-file.html#object-lifestyle-configuration

Comment: I also tried object without success.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you come to class and change logic from here, if it's your module, and can use another way like plugin, preference for changing template.

Hope it help!

Comment: Hello, this is not an answer to my question, it is a comment and it is not helpful either.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misunderstood how the DI works a bit. Based on the method you wanted to call to get the array of templates in your example above, you could update your class to use the helper for getting the array of templates like this:

```
use Fooman\PdfDesign\Model\Api\DesignInterface;
use Company\PdfDesign\Helper\Table\Extras;

class CompanyDesign implements DesignInterface
{
    ...
    
    public function __construct(
        Extras $helper,
        array $templateFiles = []
    ) {
        $templateFiles['extras'] = $helper->getTemplate();
        $this->templateFiles = $templateFiles;
    }
    
    ...

    public function getTemplateFiles()
    {
        return $this->templateFiles;
    }

    ...
}
```